# Is this a serious lexical context problem for antlr4 parsers.?

Tags: antlr4, tokenize

The WOOL language allows the following constructs:

```
  [[ text | NodeName ]]
  [[ NodeName ]]
  [[ text | NodeName | text ]]
```

Where text should be tokenized as is typed, including spaces and whatever (accept for | ] )
Where NodeName is an identifier not a text
The problem seems to me that the lexical tokenizer cannot decide if what follows the [[ should be seen as a text or an identifier ( NodeName ) .

How to solve this in antlr4 ?

Here is a minimal grammar

```
parser grammar WParser;
options { tokenVocab=WLexer;}

// start rule of grammar 
program: replies EOF ;

// a reply list may contain max one special reply
replies : reply* specialreply? reply* ;

// a reply may cointain one or two pipe characters
// it always contains a nodeName 
reply : LBOX CHAR PIPE nodeName RBOX
      | LBOX CHAR PIPE nodeName PIPE 
CHAR RBOX ;

specialreply : LBOX nodeName RBOX ;


nodeName : CHAR 
    | CHAR DOT CHAR;

 ----- WLexer.g4 ------------
```

lexer grammar WLexer;

```
COMMENT_TXT : '//' ~( '\r' | '\n' )* -> skip ;
WS: [\n\r\f]+ -> skip ;              // in this mode spaces are not skipped

LBOX : '[' ;
RBOX : ']' ;
PIPE : '|' ;
DOT  : '.' ;

ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
CHAR : ~( '\f' | '\n' | '\r' | '[' | ']' | '>' | '|' | '<' | '/' | '=' | '$' )+ ;

 -------- input example ----------

[this is some text. | NodeName ]
[ NodeName ]
[this is :|  NodeName | some more text. ]

  ---- The problem -----
```

a nodeName is an identifier, not a text!
but if I use ID instead of CHAR I get error message

```
line 1:21 no viable alternative at input '[this is some text. | NodeName '
```

Comment: Hi. Do you have some lexical rules that don't match the way you expect?  Easier to understand. thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the well known keywords-as-identifier problem. Search for that here at SO. If that's not the case then please add a minimal grammar here and tell us what you actually expected.

Comment: I put a minimal grammar and lexicon with an example and the error message. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CHAR` rule matches similar input like your `ID` rule (e.g. all latin lower and upper case letters). But because `ID` is listed before `CHAR` the latter will never match such input.

And since the order of the items (text and node name) can freely be changed I'm afraid there's no solution for your problem. At least not by simply parsing the input.

You could make one rule out of `CHAR` and `ID` and then check the individual tokens after parsing the input. If one contains letters not allowed in `CHAR` or contains a dot then it must be a node name. Otherwise it's just text.

Comment: “ …I’m afraid there is no solution to your problem.” 
Okay, that was what I wanted to know. A limitation of ANTLR. Thanks for your suggestion.